# r - Can you rearrange legend labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Apparently worded it terribly first time so here is what I mean. The legend looks like this:

10%

15%

20%

25%

30%

35%

40%

45%

5%

50%

This is done automatically. Does anyone know if you can just move the 5% to the top manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reorder ggplot legend labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313619/reorder-ggplot-legend-labels)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to reorder the corresponding factor before plotting, e.g.

```
mydata$percentage <- with(mydata,
        factor(percentage,levels=gtools::mixedsort(levels(percentage))))
```

That should probably work, but a reproducible example would be better.